# What are the names of the weapons in Rebel Moon?

Tags: weapon, rebel-moon

After watching Zack Snyder's *Rebel Moon*, I really liked the look of the weapons. I found information about how the weapons are supposed to work, but I can't find any names for them.

There are two notable weapon types:

Plasma based guns (Like blasters from SW)
[image]

I saw the guns were called [Lava Cork weapons](https://rebel-moon.fandom.com/wiki/Lava_cork_weaponry) on fandom, but there are no references. In an interview Snyder talks about how the weapons work, but doesn't name them.

> Okay, well it's not really lava. It’s the way I describe it. So don't get too hung up on lava (laugh). Everybody loves lava and that is true. But it's more just like a visual, whenever I try and describe it. Also, I say like, you know when metal drips out of a foundry? That's what the bullets are like. They're some sort of liquid plasma metal. So if I fired it, it would splash into the wall. But you don't make a huge … almost like if you shot it into a piece of metal, you’d have this beautiful kind of cratered – like a drop of water that got frozen, you know? … It's not super forgiving (when it hits people). (laugh) We definitely have a huge R and D period ahead of us for how that does look. Maybe it just passes cleanly through you. I don't know. That might be nice. It cauterizes (the wound).

And glowing swords (Lightsabers)
[image]

I found less information about these but it seems like they are normal swords that are heated to the point of glowing.

I know the film is new and is probably light on lore, but are there any official names for either of these weapons?

Comment: The whole thing is a knockoff of Star Wars. I'm assuming those are firesabres or lightscimitars or something equally non-actionable

Comment: @Valorum But there's also the spears. SW didn't have spears! (Snyder included a spear scene that could have come straight from his own 300 movie.  And the attack just happened to find that one vulnerable point in the Death Star, oops I mean The Kings Gaze)

Comment: What kind of names are you looking for? Perhaps what the production team called them as they were designing and filling, etc.?

Comment: @ToddWilcox Im looking for official in universe names for them but I know they weren't stated in the film so we're kinda limited. If there are any interviews or documents stating a name I would take it for now.